# Strange issue setting height of input[type="text"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I seem to be having a very strange problem with setting the height of the input boxes.

As soon as I set the height of the input box, the DIVS above seem to strech.

A noticeable example is once the height is set, the background-image stretches, along with all other divs in "mainContent class" but as soon as the height is removed from the input box, everything is normal

Has anyone noticed this problem before, and provide some help?

**CODE HERE: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQeedZ**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="leftmenu">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="http://callmenick.com/theme/callmenick/img/logo.svg" alt=""/>
                </div>

                <div class="social">
                    <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-youtube"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-vine"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-tumblr"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="nav">
                    <ul class="navigation">
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll" href="#videos">Videos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mainContent">
                <div id="home">
                    <div>
                        <h1>It's Magic</h1>
                        <p>You just need to believe!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="videos">
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="wow clock bounceIn">Videos</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="gallery">
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="wow rubberBand">Gallery</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="about">
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="wow zoomIn">About</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="contact">
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="wow rollIn">Contact</h1>

                        <div class="formOuter">
                            <form method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name"/>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number"/>
                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"/>
                                <textarea id="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                         <div class="copyright">
                            <p>&copy; Arshdeep Soni 2015. All Rights Reserved.</p>
                            <p>Website Designed and Managed by Arshdeep Soni</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="footer">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Subscribe</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {            margin:0 auto;
                padding:0px;
            }

            html, body {
                margin:0 auto;
                padding:0px;
                min-height: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            /*Main Container for Body*/
            .container {
                position: relative;
                display: table;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .container > div {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            .leftmenu {
                position: fixed;
                width: 22%;
                min-height: 100%;
                margin-left: 0px;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 99;
                background-color: #28aadc;
                overflow-y:auto;
            }

            .leftmenu > h1 {
                font-size: 45px;
                width: auto;
                color:white;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: 'arkhip';
                padding: 10px 0px 50px 0px;
            }

            .logo {
                display: block;
                width: 60px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                height: 60px;
                -webkit-transition: .3s;
                transition: transform .3s;
            }

            .logo:hover {
                transform: rotate(180deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
            }

            .leftmenu .social {
                position: relative;
                color: #00648c;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 10px 0px 35px 0px;
            }

            .leftmenu .social .fa {
                font-size: 20px;
                margin-left: 3px;
                margin-right: 3px;
            }

            .leftmenu .social .fa:hover {
                color:white;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .leftmenu .nav {
                position: relative;
                height: auto;
                padding-bottom: 60px;
            }

            .leftmenu .nav ul {
                height: auto;
                width: auto;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .leftmenu .nav ul li {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .leftmenu .nav ul li > a {
                margin-top: 5px;
                width:80%;
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color:#00648c;
                font-family: 'arkhip';
                font-size: 15px;
                padding:5px;
            }

            .leftmenu .nav ul li > a:hover {
                color:white;
            }

            .footer {
                position: fixed;
                bottom:0px;
                left: 0px;
                width:22%;
                z-index: 99999;
                height: 40px;
                background-color:#00648c;
            }

            .footer > div {
                position: relative;
                top:50%;
                transform: translateY(-50%);
            }

            .footer ul {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .footer ul li {
                color: #31a9d7;
                display: inline-flex;
                font-family: 'arial';
                font-size: 13px;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }

            .footer ul li a {
                color:#31a9d7;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .footer ul li a:hover {
                color:white;
            }

            .mainContent {
                display: table;
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width:78%;
                max-width: none;
                margin:0 auto;
                margin-right: 0px;
                left: 22%;
            }

            #home {
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                background-image: url("https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/126/387606063_408c203f6c_b.jpg");
                background-size: cover;
            }       

            #home > div {
                position: relative;
                top:50%;
                -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
                height: auto;
            }

            #home > div > h1, #home > div > p {
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                color:white;
                font-family: 'arkhip;'
            }

            #home > div > h1 {
                -webkit-transform: translate(0, -500px);
                font-size: 100px;
                font-family: 'arkhip';
                margin:0 auto;
            }

            #home > div > p {
                -webkit-transform: translate(0, 300px);
                text-align: center;
                margin:0 auto;
                font-family: 'arkhip';
                font-size: 18px;
            }


            #videos {
                background-color:black;
            }

            .mainContent > div > div > h1 {
                color:white;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: 'arkhip';
                font-size: 60px;
                padding-top: 20px;

            }

            #about {
               background-color:white;
            }

            #about > div > h1 {
                color:#078dff;
            }

            #gallery {
                background-color:red;
            }

            #contact {
                position: relative;
                background-color:black;
            }


            .formOuter {
                position: relative;
                border:1px solid red;
                width: 70px;
                margin:0 auto;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }

input[type="text"] {
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
                wow = new WOW(
                {
                    boxClass: 'wow',
                    animatedClass: 'animated',
                    offset: 100
                }
                );
                wow.init();
            });

            $(window).load(function() {
                $("#home > div > p").fadeIn(1500);
                $("#home > div > h1, #home > div > p").css("-webkit-transform", "translate(0px, 0px)");            
                $("#home > div > h1, #home > div > p").css("transition-duration","2s");
            });

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
                });
            });
```

Comment: `* {margin: 0 auto}`, are you sure?

Comment: Showing the codepen in two different browsers doesn't reveal any difference between whether I insert a different height for the input or not. However, there is a huge difference between SeaMonkey and Chromium. Chromium displays a large picture on top, SeaMonkey only displays the top 200 pixels or so of the picture, and it has the words "It's Magic" in it.